# Google Places API how to get recently added places

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I would like to create an application to show new restaurants/pubs in my city.

I didn't find any easy option to achieve that such as "added today", "show by the date". The only one idea I find is to use query:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restaurants+in+Poznań
```

unfortunately this is expensive solution and not effective - searching in all data every few days to find something new.

Do you know maybe any better idea to find those data?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?  AFAIK there's no way to get the X most recent photos on your area, but I think you can get the most recent photos for individual places,

Comment: @Aloysius I'm looking to get new recently opened restaurants in my city last day or week - I need to get less than for the whole query search like in my example request. Any better solution to get that will be better for me.

Comment: I could be wrong, but AFAIK there's no way to directly get recently opened restaurants.  Maybe if your query is like "new restaurants in NYC" it might do this, but I'm not sure if that would work or not.